# Python Flask - get the userList from http://localhost:8080/users

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am new to Flask and wanted to develop a micro-service application that can get the data from other microservice (written in spring boots) running in http://localhost:8080/users.

The data looks like this:

```
{"userList":[{"userId":1,"name":"x","email":"x@gmail.com","address":"add1","phone":"123","accountNo":"0000001"},{"userId":2,"name":"y","email":"x@gmail.com","address":"add1","phone":"123","accountNo":"0000001"}
```

My code is like below:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import logging
app = Flask(__name__)

os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'
r = request.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080')

@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def cust_search(email):
    json = request.get_json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I get the below error message when I run in venv:

```
  File "", line 13, in <module>
    r = request.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080')
  File "", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/covid_service/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/covid_service/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

For what you are doing, you need to use the builtin `requests` module.

```
import requests
users = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080').json()
```

`flask.request` is different than `requests`. It used for handling request data passed to the server, typically from a form post, and as you stated requires an active HTTP request.

Comment: @app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def cust_search():
    users = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/users').json()
    print(users)

Comment: File "/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/covid_service/alert.py", line 32, in cust_search
    users = request.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/users').json()
  File "/covid_service/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: import requests
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def cust_search():
    r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/users')
    users = request.form.get('userList')
    print(users)

Comment: @Aavik What exactly is the problem for the 1st and 3rd comments? The 2nd comment was probably by my typo in the answer, but there is no traceback in the other comments

Comment: [2020-07-28 17:32:55,312] ERROR in app: Exception on /users [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "//app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/app.py", line 2098, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The" TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response.The function either returned None or ended without return

Comment: `The view function did not return a valid response` -> Your `cust_search` function is a route, but it doesn't return anything. Flask routes require something to be returned

Comment: Thanks. But the users = request.get_json() or users = request.form.get('userList') return null

Comment: This is starting to go down a different path than what your original question described, probably due to various other issues in the code. See what you can do to figure it out :)